# How can I remove elements by columns number from a list?

Tags: r, list, function

I've like to remove elements in a list, if the number of elements are smaller than 3.

For this I try:

```
#Create a list

my_list <- list(a = c(3,5,6), b = c(3,1,0), c = 4, d = NA)
my_list

$a
[1] 3 5 6

$b
[1] 3 1 0

$c
[1] 4

$d
[1] NA

# Thant I create a function for remove the elements by my condition:

delete.F  <-  function(x.list){   
    x.list[unlist(lapply(x.list, function(x) ncol(x)) < 3)]}

delete.F(my_list)
```

And I have as output:

```
Error in unlist(lapply(x.list, function(x) ncol(x)) < 3) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to create a logical expression with `lengths` and use that for subsetting the `list`

```
my_list[lengths(my_list) >=3]
#$a
#[1] 3 5 6

#$b
#[1] 3 1 0
```

Note that in the example, it is a `list` of `vector`s and not a `list` of `data.frame`.  the `ncol/nrow` is when there is a `dim` attribute - `matrix` checks TRUE for that, as do `data.frame`

---

If we want to somehow use `lapply` (based on some constraints), create the logic  with `length`

```
unlist(lapply(my_list, function(x) if(length(x) >=3 ) x))
```

If we need to create the index with `lapply`, use `length` (but it would be slower than `lengths`)

```
my_list[unlist(lapply(my_list, length)) >= 3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use  unlist(lapply()) and this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Isabel  What is your expected output?  If it is the first two elements of the `list`, this solution provides that

Comment: @Isabel  You can check the updated solution with `lapply`

Comment: `delete.F  <-  function(x.list){   
    x.list[unlist(lapply(x.list, function(x) lengths(x)) >=3)]}`
 `delete.F(my_list)`
`Error in unlist(lapply(x.list, function(x) lengths(x)) >= 3) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double`

Comment: @Isabel If you check my code, I didn't use `x.list[` it is just `unlist(lapply(.`

Comment: @Isabel If you meant to get the index `my_list[unlist(lapply(my_list, length)) >= 3]`

Answer (score 1):

Here are few more options. Using `Filter` in base R

```
Filter(function(x) length(x) >=3, my_list)

#$a
#[1] 3 5 6

#$b
#[1] 3 1 0
```

Or using `purrr`'s `keep` and `discard`

```
purrr::keep(my_list, ~length(.) >= 3)

purrr::discard(my_list, ~length(.) < 3)
```